# Как найти все вхождения определенного слова в тексте?

Tags: python, linux, selenium

Хочу посчитать количество определенного слова в html странице на Python.

С помощью Selenium я получаю html страницу:

```py
html = driver.page_source
```

В Linux эта команда выглядела бы вот так:

```
cat html | grep -o 'Registered' | wc -l
```

Как выполнить те же действия, но с помощью Python и не записывая html в отдельный файл?

Comment: Нельзя использовать регулярные выражения для языков типа XML. Используйте XPath и класс ElementTree.

Answer (score 1):

Свою задачу я решил таким образом:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, "lxml")
count_of_phone = 0
for i in soup.find_all('td'):
    if 'Registered' in i.text:
        count_of_phone += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
...
html = driver.page_source
word = 'page'
count = len(re.findall(f'{word}[,:.!<]?', line))
```

Comment: `\b` наверное лучше, а вообще проблем тут много, начиная с того, что парсить XML с помощью regexp — в корне ошибочно.

Comment: @0andriy спасибо, учту